# Is this a SPDT On-On switch?

Tags: switches, spdt

I want to install a Master Switch on a paramotor using the correct switch.

Would appreciate your help to clarify the specific type so I can order the correct one from Mouser or Digikey online.

Master On/Off Switch

1. Off position is Normally Closed circuit to ground the paramotor coil wire so engine cannot be started,
2. ON position is Normally Open that when closed completes a circuit through the start button to the relay to operate the starter motor.

Manufacturer's diagram shown below.

[image: Paramotor Master Switch]

Is this called a "SPDT On-On" switch for ordering purposes?

Comment: there is more than a switch type ... there is also a voltage rating and a current rating ..... what is printed on the old switch?

Comment: Do you know how the switch needs to operate? Do you have the original part? Do you flip it one way and it stays in that position, or does it return when released? As drawn & labeled it looks a bit like a relay contact.  In a relay contact there is a Normally Closed position (non energized), and there is a Normally Open position (energized).  There are hand operated switches that mimic the operation of a relay contact, your hand (or finger) would be the energizing input.  As in another comment that type of switch could be called a SPDT switch with a momentary On position.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you need a SPDT switch. Note that the notations in red on your diagram do not refer to the switch itself but its use in the circuit. A SPDT switch does not have normally open, normally closed contacts. It just has 2 ON positions.

Comment: An SPDT *can* have normally open and normally closed contacts, if it's a momentary switch.